# import text file into mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a text file, one "thing" on each line.

I also have a mysql table:
id (auto increment)
thing (varchar)

I want to get the text from the textfile into mysql.  What is the best way to do this?

I thought about making it into an array in php and adding it through that into the mysql but is there an easier way?

edit: the file has 50,000 lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see [mysqlimport](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlimport.html)